# Loading custom fonts into my app (Titanium Studio iPhone)

Tags: iphone, ios, customization, font-face, titanium-mobile

I am new to Titanium Studio mobile development and I'm developing an iPhone application. I came across that Iphone includes some font which are there in Mac from the below link,

But I would like to load my own font (OTF or TTF) file and use it in my application. Can anybody help me with solution. Thanks is advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Video tutorial :**

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/appcelerator/titanium-mobile-custom-font/

**Steps in Appcelerator Blog :**

http://developer.appcelerator.com/blog/2010/04/adding-custom-fonts-to-ipad.html

Comment: The video tutorial is helpful. Thanks.